# Python - Index of duplicate item in list

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to find the index of a sub-list return the value with the same index of another sub-list. I keep on running into a problem when I have duplicates, since it just returns the lowest index.

```
lines = [ [ 1 , 1], [3, 4] ]
x = 0
while x < (len(lines)-1):
    for ch in lines[x]:
        print lines[x+1][lines[x].index(ch)]
    x += 1
```

I wanted to get an output of

```
3
4
```

but I am getting

```
3
3
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but wouldn't this just be `lines[1]`? For each item in `lines[0]`, you're wanting to find the index of that occurrence of the item (not the first occurrence), and return the corresponding item from `lines[1]`. But the sequence of indices that will generate is just 0, 1, 2, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand. In both iteration so the for loop `ch` is `1` so `lines[x].index(ch)` will be 1. Why not just loop through the second in a more straight forward fashion:

```
lines = [ [ 1 , 1], [3, 4] ]
x = 0
y=0
while x < (len(lines)-1):
    while y < len(lines[x]):
        print lines[x+1][y]
        y= y+1
    x = x+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your len(lines)-1 by len(lines) in the while statement, because i think it doesnt tests all the values.

Comment: I only wanted the value of the next sublist, from the index of the curent sublist. Once I have reached last substring I would get an error, hence why I used len(lines)-1.

Answer (score 0):

`index()` finds the first occurence of the passed element of the list, so whenever you call `[1,1].index[1]`, you will always get 0.

If your goal is to simply access the item of list b from the index in list a-

```
a = [1,1]
b = [3,4]
for x in range(0,len(a)):
    print b[x]
```